# running a wcf service on an Azure VM

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-virtual-machine

I can browse to it from the local desktop on the server, I setup my endpoints in Azure for port 8053, I can't hit the url remotely though.  I assume it's  myservice.cloudapp.net:8053/service.svc.

Did I miss a step?

Comment: is that just like on a normal server or a special Azure firewall?

Comment: have you tried accessing it using the public IP?

Comment: yes, same thing, it times out